# Run executable using wildcard path

Tags: powershell

I have an executable in a directory that is versioned, so the directory changes when the tool is updated.

The current command I run is the following:

```
.\packages\Chutzpah.4.1.0\tools\chutzpah.console.exe .\Tests\chutzpah.json
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
.\packages\Chutzpah**\tools\chutzpah.console.exe .\Tests\chutzpah.json
```

Windows command line [doesn't like to expand wildcards](https://superuser.com/q/460598/27229) but I'm hoping this is possible with powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer here could be to use `resolve-path` which

> Resolves the wildcard characters in a path, and displays the path contents.

So in practice you should be able to do something like this.

```
$path = Resolve-Path ".\packages\Chutzpah**\tools\chutzpah.console.exe" -Relative
& $path ".\Tests\chutzpah.json"
```

Note that `Resolve-Path` has the potential to match more that one thing.

Comment: I'm okay with matching more than one because I know there will only be one. Resolve-Path looks like the right way to go but this script doesn't run for me. I get `Select-Object : Property "Path" cannot be found.`

Comment: `Resolve-Path -Relative` return `String` not `PathInfo`. So, you have to remove `-Relative` or `Select-Object`.

Comment: @PetSerAl That is what I get for coding on the go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Windows will expand the wild cards, but if the non-wildcard portion is not unique, you'll get the (I think) FIRST match.

So I think that really your problem is

"How do I tell which version I should be executing"

Which, if you have project files, etc., you might be able to extract from there.

In fact, you might well be wanting to extract something from the solution packages.config file, assuming that the .\packages\ prefix is there because you are wanting to run tests against files that are in a NuGet package.

Can you supply some more details?

EDIT:
OK, so you probably need to do something like System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path, pattern)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w(v=vs.110).aspx

And depending on what you'd done with "Chutzpah" you'll get one or more matches that you could use to select the correct path.

Comment: Windows will expand if I hit tab while typing but it wont expand if I run as a script above in either `bat` or `ps1`. I get "The system cannot find the path specified".